# Robot Framework Output XML import using GITLAB yaml into JIRA (Xray)

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, robotframework, jira-rest-api

So, I have run a robot framework job using Intellij and this creates a output XML file. I now need to get the results into JIRA (xray/cloud) using GITLAB. Has anyone created an yaml file to do this? Can anyone let me know how to do this? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

- Configure Gitlab to run Robot Framework tests, you have to run tests on remote machine where Gitlab has access not your local machine via IDE.
- At this moment Xray has no Gitlab plugin but you can use REST API to upload xml file. You can use curl, something like this:

  ```
  curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u $jira_user:$jira_password -F "file=@report/output.xml" "$jira_server_url/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/junit?projectKey=CALC"
  ```

Check this doc for more infomation https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+GitLab

Comment: Thanks Bodur. I will have a look. At the moment I am running Intellij on my own laptop. Wondering if I can just change the curl command to look at a directory on my machine to pickup the output xml?

Comment: Yes, you can give a try.